# Defining the set of all algebraic numbers: Help with index for the union

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing problem 2.2 from Rudin, which asks to show that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable. I was looking at the [solution](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%202.pdf?sequence=10&isAllowed=y) provided here (image also included), and understand the general idea of the proof, but I'm not sure why the index starts at $N=2$ instead of $N=1$.

Explicitly, if we are defining $A_N$ as the set of numbers satisfying $P_N$, where $P_N$= $\{(a_{n}x^{n} +a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}x + a_{0}):  \mid n \mid + \mid a_0 \mid + \mid a_1 \mid + ... + \mid a_n \mid = N\}$,

why is the set of algebraic numbers $\bigcup\limits_{N=2}^{\infty} A_{N}$ and not $ \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} A_{N}$?

[image: Solution to Rudin 2.2]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner wouldn't that mean that the elements of $A_1$ are also algebraic, since all rationals are algebraic? Is it necessary to exclude $A_1$?

Comment: Maybe $n$ has to be at least $1$ and so does $|a_0|+|a_1|+...+|a_n|$, so their sum $N$ must be at least $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomials in $A_1$ are the polynomials
$$P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$$
satisfying
$$n + |a_0| + |a_1| + \ldots + |a_n| = 1.$$
(Note that $n \ge 0$, so I omitted the absolute value brackets). Instantly, this tells me that $n \le 1$, since $n$ plus a bunch of non-negative integers is equal to $1$. So, either we have $n = 0$, which gives us a constant polynomial, or $n = 1$, which gives us a polynomial of the form
$$P(x) = a_0 + a_1x.$$

In the former case, we have $0 + |a_0| = 1$, which gives us two cases: $P(x) = -1$, $P(x) = 1$. These have no roots whatsoever! So, we don't need to include these cases.

In the latter case, we have $1 + |a_0| + |a_1| = 1 \implies a_0 = a_1 = 0$. This gives us the zero polynomial, which is purposely excluded (if we counted the roots of the zero polynomial, then every number would be algebraic).

So, $A_1$ contains no polynomials with any roots, except the forbidden zero polynomial.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense! Thank you!!

Comment: @kijontrona You're welcome!

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the sets didn't exclude the possibility of $a_n = 0$ or $a_{n-1} = 0$, etc, so we can actually increase $n$ as much as we want, adding in new $0$ coefficients. This implies $A_N \subseteq A_{N+1}$, which means we really could start our union from any point, not just $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Set of algebraic numbers contain the roots of polynomial over integers. Since number of roots of any degree of polynomial is finite (Fundamental theorem of algebra) and those polynomial are countable because integers are countable.  Since countable union of countable set is countable implying algebraic numbers are countable.

Comment: I understand. I was specifically asking about the index on the union. Do you have any insight as to why we have to exclude $A_1$ when defining the set of all algebraic numbers?

Comment: When N=1, $A_1 =\{a_0+a_1x+....a_nx^n : |n| + |a_0|+......|a_n|=1 \}$ and $n+ |a_0|+......|a_n|=1 \implies$ only one of $\{n,a_0,...a_n\}$ is 1 and rest are zero since everything in the sum is absolute value of integers. Hence, $A_1$ is set of the zero polynomial.